# How to check diagonals in NQueens?

Tags: java, function, testing, methods

Im making the NQueens program in java but I am having trouble checking the diagonals. Right now I just go through the array in a way so it goes to the next diagonal spot but it is giving me out of bounds after going through the first possibility. Is there a different way to do this? Am i doing it wrong?

Here is the part that is giving me the array out of bounds exception

```
private boolean checkLowerDiag(int row, int col)
{
    if(col == 0)
    {
        return false;             
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = row, j = col; i < myNumsQueen && j >= 0;  i++, j--)
        {
            if(myBoard[i+1][j-1] == true) // this line is the out of bounds
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is my entire code

```
package model;

public class NQueensModel
{
    private int myNumsQueen;
    public int myPossibilities=0;
    private boolean[][] myBoard;
    private static NQueensModel myModel = new NQueensModel(4);

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        System.out.println(myModel.solvePuzzle());


        System.out.println(myModel.myPossibilities);
       // System.out.println(myPossibilities);


    }
    public NQueensModel(int nQueens)
    {
        myNumsQueen = nQueens;
        myPossibilities=0;
        myBoard = new boolean[myNumsQueen][myNumsQueen];
    }
    public boolean solvePuzzle()
    {

        return this.solvePuzzle(0);

    }
    private boolean solvePuzzle(int ncolumn)
    {
        if(ncolumn>myNumsQueen-1)
        {
            myPossibilities++;
//            return true;

        }
        int i;

        for( i =0; i<myNumsQueen;i++)
        {

            if(this.isSafeMove(i, ncolumn)==true)
            {

                this.placeQueen(i,ncolumn);
                System.out.println(i+ " " + ncolumn);
                if(this.solvePuzzle(ncolumn+1)==true)
                {

                    return true;

                }
                this.removeQueen(i, ncolumn);
                System.out.println("remove: " + i+ " " + ncolumn);
            }


        }

        return false;

    }
    private int solveCount(int count, int col)
    {
        for(int j = 0 ; j<col; j++){
            if(myModel.solvePuzzle(j)==true){
             count++;
        }
        else if(myModel.solvePuzzle(j)==false){
            return count;
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i =0 ; i<col;i++){
                count = solveCount(count, col+1);
            }
            return count;
        }
        return count;
        }
        return count;

    }
    private boolean isSafeMove(int row, int col)
    {

         if(this.checkLowerDiag(row, col)==true ||this.checkUpperDiag(row, col)==true ||this.checkLeft(row,col)==true)
         {
             return false;
         }
        else
        {

            return true;
        }


    }
    private boolean checkUpperDiag(int row, int col)
    {    
        if(row==0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i=row, j = col; i>=0 && j>=0; i--, j--)
            {
                if(myBoard[i][j]==true)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    private boolean checkLowerDiag(int row, int col)
    {

        if(col==0 )
        {           
            return false;             
        }
        else
        {

            for(int i = row, j = col; i<myNumsQueen && j>=0;  i++, j--)
            {
                if(myBoard[i+1][j-1]==true)
                {
                    return true;

                }


            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    private boolean checkLeft(int row, int col)
    {
        if(col==0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else 
        {
            for(int i = col; i>=0; i--)
            {
                if(myBoard[row][i]==true)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
    private boolean placeQueen(int row, int col)
    {
        myBoard[row][col] = true;
        return true;
    }
    private boolean removeQueen(int row, int col)
    {
        myBoard[row][col] = false;
        return false;
    }
//    public String toString()
//    {
//        
//    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: What happens when j becomes 0?

Comment: when j becomes 0, it means it is at the very first column in the board